# How to remove the message "This copy of Windows is not genuine" (build 7601)

Tags: windows-7

I have a Dell machine as well as a virtual machine both running Windows 7, which gave the error message "This copy of Windows 7 is not genuine" about a year or so ago. Back then I was told to run the following commands in order to restore the OS to it's normal state:

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:971033 /quiet
net stop sppsvc /y
del %windir%\system32\7B296FB0-376B-497e-B012-9C450E1B7327-5P-0.C7483456-A289-439d-8115-601632D005A0 /ah
del %windir%\system32\7B296FB0-376B-497e-B012-9C450E1B7327-5P-1.C7483456-A289-439d-8115-601632D005A0 /ah
del %windir%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoftwareProtectionPlatform\tokens.dat
del %windir%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoftwareProtectionPlatform\cache\cache.dat
net start sppsvc
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk <key>
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato
taskkill /IM slui.exe
```

After performing the steps above, everything worked fine until I recently got the message again. When I perform these steps again, they no longer work.

They keys I used to activate Windows 7 are legitimate keys, and they have worked for years. I tried to activate both machines again, but I'm unable to activate them (no reason: Windows just says it cannot be activated).

How can I get rid of this message, and have a genuine Windows 7 machine (real and virtual) again?

Thanks!

Edit: the Windows 7 keys are NOT OEM keys, they are keys for Windows 7 Enterprise and did not come with the machine (which is made to order and not from one manufacturer).

Edit 2: when the message first appeared, I could just keep on using the machine without any hassles. The commands I described just got rid of the message. Now however, the machine is practically unusable - each time it boots, it takes longer to show the taskbar and the message that Windows is not genuine. As long as this message and the taskbar are not shown, you can't do anything with the computer (neither real nor VM).

Answer (score 4):

> The keys I used to activate Windows 7 are legitimate keys, and they
> have worked for years. I tried to activate both machines again, but
> I'm unable to activate them (no reason: Windows just says it cannot be
> activated).

The message is very likely correct.

Most (not all) licenses for operating systems for individuals are OEM licenses (sold that way on a physical machine normally) and so not transferable to another machine (real or virtual).

This is most likely the cause here.

The solution is to obtain a Retail (non-OEM) license for Windows 7.

I do not think you can purchase this from Microsoft any more (not 100% certain), but you should be able to obtain a legitimate Retail Windows 7 license on eBay or like source.

I have a Windows 7 VM here, and I obtained a Retail (non-OEM) license from my supplier when Windows 7 was still in support.  The resulting VM stays activated and has done for years.

**Later comment:**  "the Windows 7 keys are Enterprise keys which I was given by my employer (each employer gets a set of keys for personal use at our company). I've tried activating the key via the KMS of my employer and directly with Microsoft"

In this case the KMS activation may have expired and your company would need to give you new KMS keys.  Companies needed to make special arrangements with Microsoft to keep Windows 7 going past the official end of life.  You may need to ask your employer for further information.

Comment: Windows 7 is indeed not sold by Microsoft. Microsoft only sells the current version of Windows and Windows Server. Granted, Windows 11 is the exception, since Microsoft only currently sells Windows 10 licenses

Comment: Getting a Windows 7  License from Ebay is risky - last I looked many of the legit licenses wern't.

Comment: You have to search carefully and ask questions. My Vista Business VM CD and license came from eBay and I looked very carefully. Money back if it would not activate. It did activate and still runs.

Comment: @John Thanks for your reply, but the license keys are not OEM licenses. The computer was built from parts by myself several years ago, and the Windows 7 keys are Enterprise keys which I was given by my employer (each employer gets a set of keys for personal use at our company). I've tried activating the key via the KMS of my employer and directly with Microsoft, but neither option works. The thing is, it has always worked until recently, so I'm stumped why this suddenly no longer works...

Comment: The KMS keys may need to be renewed and your employer would need to help you with this. I amended my post to include this.